# Passing values from jQuery to PHP in same page instantly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, msgbox

I have written a PHP program to confirm deletion of data through jQuery confirm message (Refer: http://rathur.fr/jQuery/MsgBox/) and record the result back to the same page itself instantly. If the page refreshes, it'll return back its state to previous.

The part of line is below:

```
print "
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.msgbox('<br/>Are you sure you want to delete the selected record from the database?', {
    type : 'confirm'
  }, function(result){
    $('#output').text(result);
    var output = result;
  });
});
</script>";
```

I want to get the result of the action button to PHP variable instantly, like below (*just a trial*):

```
$x = $_SESSION['output']; OR
$x = $_POST['output']; OR
$x = print "<div id=\"output\"></div>"; OR
$x = some_function(output);
```

Please help me, or suggest if there is other better options.

Comment: You would need to POST the data back to php with an AJAX call in order to use server-side code on the 2nd pass.

Comment: Can you specify the way to alter the existing jQuery script?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Ajax call to a Php File by an event : Click on a button.

**Javascript client side :**

```
 $("body").on("click", "#mybutton", function() {
            var mydata = $("#form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/api.php",
                data: {data : mydata},
                timeout: 6e3,
                error: function(a, b) {
                    if ("timeout" == b) $("#err-timedout").slideDown("slow"); else {
                        $("#err-state").slideDown("slow");
                        $("#err-state").html("An error occurred: " + b);
                    }
                },
                success: function(a) {
                    var e = $.parseJSON(a);
                    if (true == e["success"]) {
                        $("#action").html(e['message']);
                        // here is what you want, callback Php response content in Html DOM
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

**Next in your Php code simply do after any success function :**

```
if ($result) {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'success' => true,
                'msg' => "Nice CallBack by Php sent to client Side by Ajax Call"
            ));
        }
```

Comment: How can I add Ajax to PHP call script with the existing jQuery script? I also need the existing jQuery script to run/display the jQuery alert message, as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery to POST the data to a PHP script using AJAX if you want to use the second pass.

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ has many functions and tutorials on writing AJAX functions and handling return data. In particular, look at the `post()` function.